# How to get data from another table without default ID from Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js, relation

I have 2 tables.

Booking.

1. id = integer (default from sequelize)
2. id_booking = string

Customer.

1. id = integer (default from sequelize)
2. id_booking = string
3. agent = string

I create id_booking in Booking table, because I want to create unique ID, isnt like 'id' from sequelize just integer.

How can I get customer from Booking table, with hasmany relation?
note : the foreign key isnt id (from sequelize) but id_booking(string, unique).

My Controller

```
enter code here
db.Booking.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.Customer
  }]
})
```

My Model

```
  module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Booking = sequelize.define('Booking', {
    id_booking: DataTypes.STRING,
    agent:DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  Booking.associate = function(models) {
    Booking.hasMany(models.Customer, { foreignKey: 'id_booking'})
  };
  return Booking;
};
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the primary key then you need to specify the [`sourceKey`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#target-keys) in your [one to many](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#one-to-many-associations-hasmany-) associations, or the `targetKey` in the reverse `belongsTo()` relationship.

```
Booking.hasMany(models.Customer, {
  foreignKey: 'id_booking', 
  sourceKey: 'id_booking',
});
```

Comment: Thank you for help me, but I still didnt get data.
"sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'Customers.BookingId' in 'field list'",
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Customers` AS `Customers` ON `Booking`.`id_booking` = `Customers`.`BookingId`;"

I've changed my booking and customer relation with this, like as you said.
booking
Booking.hasMany(models.Customer, { sourceKey: 'id_booking'})

customer
Customer.belongsTo(models.Booking, { targetKey: 'id_booking'})

Thank you.

Comment: Ok done, I add foreignKey on source too.
Booking.hasMany(models.Customer, { foreignKey:'id_booking', sourceKey: 'id_booking'}). Thank you